# Npm versioning - how does this edge case work?

Tags: node.js, npm, versioning

Im trying to figure out how npm versioning works because im getting stuck on two invalid packages. Ref [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27625596/node-failes-to-install-because-of-prerelease). The module i need, serialport, get these packages invalid, "readable-stream" and "string_decoder". Serialport have downloaded this version:

```
readable-stream@1.0.27-1
```

Serialports dependency is

```
"readable-stream": "~1.0.2"
```

Readable-streams available versions are:

```
....
'1.0.26',
'1.0.27-1',
'1.0.31',
....
```

Which explains why 1.0.27-1 is picked. Because of the tilde and ~1.0.2, meaning that these three numbers have to exist in each version. Ref [Jakob Mattsson´s simple article](http://www.jakobm.com/semver-in-nodejs-and-npm)

readable-stream downloads

```
string_decoder@0.10.25-1
```

readable-stream again depends on

```
"string_decoder": "~0.10.x"
```

And string_decoders available versions are

```
....
'0.10.24',
'0.10.25-1',
'0.10.25',
'0.10.31',
'0.11.10-1'
....
```

How come that version is downloaded? Ref [the article again](http://www.jakobm.com/semver-in-nodejs-and-npm), tilde means that it has to has 0.10 in the version number, and x is whatever exists?

Why is not string_decoder@0.10.31 chosen?

I believe my problem in [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27625596/node-failes-to-install-because-of-prerelease) is related to prereleases that this extra dash is called. Im trying to gather facts to maybe seem if dependencies can get updated.

Comment: "Which explains why 1.0.27-1 is picked. Because of the tilde and ~1.0.2, meaning that these three numbers have to exist in each version."  That's not quite true.  It means that it must be at leasst 1.0.2 and < 1.1.0.  Not sure why it doesn't take 1.0.31 in this case.

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver

Comment: Yeah you might be true. Ref these lines: ~1 means >= 1.0.0 and < 2.0.0 (or "Any version starting with 1") --- ~1.4 means >= 1.4.0 and < 1.5.0 (or "Any version starting with 1.4")

But it aslo has the comment, any version starting with, meaning starting with 1.0.2. So what makes this trigger?

Comment: `~1.0.2` does not mean `any version starting with '1.0.2'`.  It's "any version >=1.0.2 <1.1.0".  So, 1.0.10 or 1.0.31 is fine.  However, prerelease versions are no longer included in ranges, so 1.0.27-1 would not be allowed.  See: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6997#issuecomment-68006017

Answer (score 0):

I recieved an answere on github, [issue answer](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6997#issuecomment-68006460), thought i would share it with the rest who might wonder:

semver range checking is done semantically, not lexically, so 1.0.31 should match with npm@2:

% semver -r '~1.0.2' 1.0.26 1.0.27-1 1.0.31 1.0.26 1.0.31 I suspect that the behavior you're seeing is due to a bundledDependency included in the package tarball.

See [Node app fails to run because of prerelease](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27625596/node-app-fails-to-run-because-of-prerelease) for a more detailed answer too why this happens.