# Why the version of node.js in my computer is higher than current official version?

Tags: node.js

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 and checking the version of Node.js:

```
$ node -v
v0.13.0-pre
```

But it's curious that the current official version is just v0.12.0! Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: *"Any suggestions?*" For what? Why you have a new version? I guess something must have installed it.

Answer (score 0):

The version installed is a pre release. you can remove and/or install a stable version (0.12.0) if you wish or use the pre release. some modules though might not work, so the stable 0.12.0 is prob a better bet.

heres a related question that goes into more details about [pre release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27625596/node-app-fails-to-run-because-of-prerelease)

Here's a quick guide (related question) to [uninstall node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650169/uninstall-node-js-using-linux-command-line) (if you want to install the stable)